# How to calculate weight on cumulus

Tags: weight, benchmarking, cumulus

I am a bit confused about this. If I have a pr on Substrate that requires a companion on Cumulus that adds to the weight file for a given pallet, how do I calculate the weight? I can run the `benchmark.sh` script inside the cumulus repo locally with the local substrate directory that contains the new code, but that will generate the weight while running on my machine. What is the way to run the benchmark on the benchmarking machine for the new code when the pr on substrate is not merged yet?

I am probably missing something, so I hope someone could explain this to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think there is a good solution. Will ask internally and then answer here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benchbot can now also be used to run on *companion* merge requests, even in Cumulus.
An example command looks like this:

```
/cmd queue -v PATCH_substrate=11796 -c bench-bot $ pallet statemint assets pallet_uniques
```

This would benchmark the `uniques` pallet for the `statemint` runtime after patching the local Substrate installation to MR `11796`.
The `-v PATCH_substrate` is important to tell the to consider this as a companion to a different MR.
You can add Polkadot here as well. The output will be pushed directly to the branch, as can be see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1460#issuecomment-1193097900).

Currently it looks like its modifying the `Cargo.lock` file, I don't think that is intentional. Will be fixed shortly.